# Play framework: Sorting crud table fields

Tags: java, playframework

How do i set the sort order to DESC as default? This sort doesn't really do anything but make postedAt the only sortable item:

```
<div id="crudListTable">
    #{crud.table fields:['title', 'postedAt'], sort:['postedAt']}
        #{crud.custom 'postedAt'}
            ${object.postedAt.format("dd-MM-yyyy")}
        #{/crud.custom}
    #{/crud.table}
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this on the Entity if you want:

```
@Entity 
public class Course {
   ...
   @ManyToMany
   @OrderBy("lastname ASC")
   public List<Student> students;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to set the `order` attribute to `DESC`?

```
#{crud.table fields:['title', 'postedAt'], sort:['postedAt'], order: 'DESC'}
    ...
#{/crud.table}
```

Comment: Didnt make any diffrence. Solved it in the controller by putting params to the request object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my hack:

First thing you have to do is to implement Comparable on the class that you want to sort, and further create a compareTo method.

Next, enter the crud module in your project. In app/views/tags.crud you will find a file called relationField.html, which handles the fields for adding relations. This file is divided into two parts, one for creating select-boxes with multiple=true, and one for creating dropdown select boxes. If you want both of these sorted you will have to edit in both these cases.

Substitute `%{ _field.choices.each() { }` with `%{ _field.choices.sort().each() { }%` (basically adding groovy syntax for sorting a collection), and the input fields will be sorted.

Full example of Java-classes:

Referencing class:

`@Entity
public class Book extends Model {`

```
@Required
public String title;

@Required
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
public List<Author> authors;

@Required
@ManyToOne
public Publisher publisher;

//omitted
```

}

Referenced class:

`public class Author extends Model implements Comparable {`

```
@Required
public String firstName;
@Required
public String lastName;

public int compareTo(final Author otherAuthor) {
    if (this.lastName.equals(otherAuthor.lastName)) {
        if (this.firstName.equals(otherAuthor.firstName)) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return this.firstName.compareTo(otherAuthor.firstName);
        }
    } else {
        return this.lastName.compareTo(otherAuthor.lastName);
    }
}
//omitted
```

}

This structure compared with the hack on relationField.html will make the possibilities in the select appear sorted.